# System loses sound configuration in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, volume-control

Sometimes, while watching an embedded Facebook or YouTube video the sound stops. That happens in a matter of seconds or minutes after the video has started and varies from browser to browser (some browsers can hold sound longer than others) but eventually all of them stop playing the sound track. In such occasions, I open Sound Control, change the settings and sound resumes. But then sooner or later after that the sound stops again.

In Sound Control, in tab `Configuration` I have:

`Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450/8490 OEM / R5 230/235/235X OEM]`

With the following profiles:

```
Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (unplugged)(unavailable)
Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (unplugged)(unavailable)
Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (unplugged)(unavailable)
Off
```

Under `Built-in Audio` there are:

```
Analogue Stereo Duplex (unavailable)
Analogue Stereo Output (unplugged)(unavailable)
Analogue Stereo Input
Off
```

I observed that any `Caicos HDMI Audio` profile (except "Off", of course) works fine with (and only with) **Analogue Stereo Output (unplugged)(unavailable)**. And here's the problem: the system changes this latter profile automagically to **Analogue Stereo Input** without any action from my part, and that option does not work with neither **Digital Stereo (HDMI)**, **Digital Surround 7.1** or **Digital Surround 5.1**.

Does that make any sense? Besides, how can a (unplugged)(unavailable) profile work since it is unplugged and unavailable? What do I have to do to have the correct profile combination to "hold" permanently?

My system specs are:

```
$ sudo inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: carlos Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: BIOSTAR model: H310MHP serial: N/A 
  UEFI: American Megatrends v: 5.12 date: 12/30/2019 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-48-generic
```

```
$ lspci | grep 'Audio'
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6450 / 7450/8450/8490 OEM / R5 230/235/235X OEM]
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC891
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where my Ubuntu 20.04 kept loosing sound configuration. I had to manually choose the profile

```
Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (unplugged)(unavailable)
```

in PulseAudio Volume Control GUI Configuration tab after each reboot and after each plug-unplug of the headset, because it kept falling back to the profile

```
Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
```

which produced no sound. The following workaround stopped this problem.

I added the line

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo
```

to the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

where the code name of my soundcard `alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0` and the preferred profile `output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo`
were taken from the output of

```
pactl list cards
```

in the `Name:` and `Profiles:` sections

Now the sound setting is preserved through reboots and switching to the headset and back.